# Writing start script with different working directory

Tags: raspberry-pi, cd-command, init-script, sysvinit, camera

I installed octoprint to my raspberry pi earlier this year in order to control my 3d printers.

I've been able to make the pi control 2 printers at once using octoprint. Also I've added a second camera (USB) to view the second printer. I managed to find a way to start the second camera and edit octoprint to see the difference in the two.

My only problem is every time I start my raspberry pi up again I have to change to different a working directory:

```
cd ~/mjpg-streamer
```

then this to start the second camera:

```
./mjpg_streamer -i "./input_raspicam.so -fps 5" -o "./output_http.so -p 8090"&
```

I want to be able to write a script to start the camera on boot so I don't have to ssh to my raspberry, login, and send the commands every day. I've found a lot about writing boot scripts but nothing about changing the working directory inside it.

I've been using this to write start scripts (unsuccessfully):

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/startsecondcamera
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the startup script do the `cd` before running `mjpg_streamer`, just like you're doing manually:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /home/geilisa/mjpg-streamer
./mjpg_streamer -i "./input_raspicam.so -fps 5" -o "./output_http.so -p 8090"
```

This is assuming that your home directory is `/home/geilisa`.

You can't use `~` in the script since it's likely run by root. If running the utility as root is an issue, use `sudo -u gelisia ./mjpg_streamer ...` in the script to run it as user `gelisia` instead.

---

An alternative is to add a cron job that runs at boot:

```
@reboot cd /home/geilisa/mjpg-streamer && ./mjpg_streamer -i "./input_raspicam.so -fps 5" -o "./output_http.so -p 8090"
```

Add this in your crontab by using the command `crontab -e`. This will open an editor with your crontab (possibly an empty file). Add the above line, save, and exit.

Most cron's that I know of allows for using `@reboot` (and `@hourly`, `@daily` etc.) instead of the five job scheduling columns that usually goes before the actual command.

Comment: Thank you so much the cron job worked! I probably just messed up the script more, but that is okay. Thank you so much!